# Identifier expected on Pascal

Tags: pascal

I keep getting an error: `Identifier expected` on the code snippet below.

```
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  if (not IsUpgrade()) then
    begin
      MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:BaseAppMissing}'), mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
  else
    begin
      Result := True;
    end;
end;
```

Then when I remove the `else` part, it works just fine. What is wrong with my code? The begin-end pairing seems okay. What am I missing?

```
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  if (not IsUpgrade()) then
    begin
      MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:BaseAppMissing}'), mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Remove semicolon before else.

Comment: Line 7 should not have a semicolon `;`. In Pascal, semicolons _separate_ statements, and an if..else is a single statement. Your compiler is complaining because it does not expect the keyword `else` to begin a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolons after the `end` keywords inside the `if...then...else` clause.